# How to remove obsolete contact groups?

Tags: contacts, mojave

So with Mojave, Apple removed particularly LinkedIn and Facebook internet accounts and as a result my macOs contacts app now have LinkedIn group with hundreds of my LinkedIn contacts which I do not want to have in contacts app and I can't delete it.

[image]

Any way to remove LinkedIn group? (as well as Facebook group)

Comment: Have you tried just clicking on the group in the sidebar and hitting the delete key?  Are these Smart Groups?

Comment: @fsb these groups are not selectable in any way

Comment: How is it highlighted in the left side of the screenshot?  Can you just tab to them or use the arrow keys?  Try holding the Shift key, click on a contact name, and hit Delete.

Comment: @fsb the "All LinkedIn" is highlighted, which doesn't give any option. Attempt to delete items with Shift or any other modifier keys didn't give any result. It's totally undeletable!

Comment: Are there any contacts in that group?  If it's a Smart Group, you have to delete all the contacts in that group first.

Comment: @fsb Since I haven't created that group, then I can't tell if it's smart group or not. As you can see from the screenshot, I can't delete anything from this group. I will be more than happy to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For account groups, you need to remove or disable in the preferences. In the "Contacts" app, go to the menu bar, "Contacts" then "Accounts..." those accounts should be listed. If so, you can remove or turn them off (uncheck the "Enable this account" box) there.

Comment: Neither LinkedIn nor Facebook accounts are  listed there.